# Why does `-fforce-recomp` make ghc 7.8.2 compile twice?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I have a project that builds a single executable. With cabal, if I use the `-fforce-recomp` flag like this:

```
cabal build --ghc-options="-Wall -fforce-recomp"
```

GHC compiles every single module (all 24 of them in my project) twice. Any errors and warnings I get are exactly the same the second time around. Even if no errors occurred, it still compiles everything twice. Is this a bug?

EDIT: If I bypass cabal and manually invoke `ghc -Wall -fforce-recomp --make $PROJECT_NAME` in my source directory, I do not get this behavior. So, it probably has something to do with `cabal build` in a sandbox. Also, I've noticed that between the duplicate compilation runs, only the last one ends with the message "Linking dist/build/..." --- i.e., it compiles, compiles again, and then links.

<strike>EDIT2: OK, so I've done a search into my project's directory, and I think it's definitely a `cabal sandbox` issue. I get `*.hi` files for all my modules in `./dist/dist-sandbox-c40738d9/build/maxa/maxa-tmp/` and *again* in `./dist/build/maxa/maxa-tmp/`. I have a strong feeling that these are the footprints of the two compilation runs.</strike>

EDIT3: Well, I just realized that the two compilation runs all occur in `./dist/build/maxa/maxa-tmp/` --- it says so like this:

```
[14 of 24] Compiling Maxa.State       ( src/Maxa/State.lhs, dist/build/maxa/maxa-tmp/Maxa/State.o )
```

(I wonder how I missed it before I wrote EDIT2...). So it has nothing to do with the cabal sanbox hashcode directory.

EDIT4: Well, there is a project of mine on github that also compiles twice with `-fforce-recomp` --- you can check out the .cabal file and everything at https://github.com/listx/netherworld.

Comment: Can't reproduce with my projects. Does this happen with hackage packages as well?

Comment: Have you enabled profiling? Does GHC compile to `.p_o` instead of `.o` the second time around?

Comment: @Rhymoid: No, I have not enabled profiling (I have not enabled it with `library-profiling` or `executable-profiling` in my project's `.cabal` file. There are no `.p_o` files anywhere in my project directory. I am using a cabal sandbox, but I don't think that has anything to do with it. If no one is able to reproduce it, then I suppose it could be a hardware/filesystem issue with my Samsung SSD (perhaps something to do with file modification timestamps).

Comment: @leftaroundabout If I do `cabal install foo` it compiles the *.hi and also the *.dyn_hi files, so I guess the answer is "yes".

Comment: I get this without a sandbox on OSX. If I do, say, `cabal unpack pony`, enter pony, do `cabal configure` and then `cabal build --ghc-options="-Wall -fforce-recomp"` it is clearly building (a trivial executable) twice, similarly if I add an imported module to complicate thinsg. If I just do `cabal build`, it does half as much (it clearly has nothing to do with profiling.)  I guess I would have gone by way of `cabal clean; cabal configure; cabal build...`, so never noticed it.

Comment: Similarly if I put `ghc-options:   -Wall  -fforce-recomp` in the .cabal file. It's a slightly strange thing to put in a .cabal file of course.